# Synfusion chart control charttype hiloopenclose

Tags: winforms, charts, syncfusion

I am using Visual Studio 2010 along with Syncfusion Essential Studio 10.2.0.56.

I want to change the shape of open close symbols from horizontal lines to circle in hi low open close charttype in essential chart of syncfusion.

Can someone help me in achieving this????
I want to finally get this type of chart

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this requirement by combination of Hilo and Scatter type chart. Please set the desired symbol in Hilo and scatter chart type for your requirements. Please refer the below code snippet to achieve this,

```
    [C#]
    // chart series for Hilo.            
        ChartSeries series1 = new ChartSeries("Series 1", ChartSeriesType.HiLo);
         series1.Points.Add(1, new double[] { 8, 3 });
        series1.Points.Add(2, new double[] { 10, 2 });
        series1.Points.Add(3, new double[] { 16, 2 });
        series1.Points.Add(4, new double[] { 7, 3 });
        series1.Points.Add(5, new double[] { 12, 3 });
        this.chartControl1.Series.Add(series1);
        // symbol for Hilo chart type
        series1.Style.Symbol.Shape = ChartSymbolShape.HorizLine;
        series1.Style.Symbol.Color = Color.CadetBlue;
        series1.Style.Interior = new BrushInfo(Color.Black);


          // chart series for scatter.            
        ChartSeries series2 = new ChartSeries("Series 2", ChartSeriesType.Scatter);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            series2.Points.Add(i+1, (series1.Points[i].YValues[0] + series1.Points[i].YValues[1]) / 2);
        this.chartControl1.Series.Add(series2);
          // symbol for scatter chart type
        series2.Style.Interior = new BrushInfo(Color.LightGreen);
        series2.ZOrder = 0;

          // chart series for scatter.            
        ChartSeries series3 = new ChartSeries("Series 3", ChartSeriesType.Scatter);
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            series3.Points.Add(i + 1, (series1.Points[i].YValues[1]));
        this.chartControl1.Series.Add(series3);
       // symbol for scatter chart type
        series3.Style.Symbol.Shape = ChartSymbolShape.HorizLine;
        series3.Style.Symbol.Color = Color.Red;
```

Regards,

M. Balaji